# Splitting field of $x^m - 1$ over $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I need to find the splitting field of a polynomial $ x^m-1 \in\mathbb{F}_p[x] $.

I know that if $ \gcd(m,p)=1 $ then the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_p(z)$ where $ z $ is primitive root of unity of order $ m $.
My question is what to do if $ \gcd(m,p) \ne 1 $. How can I find the splitting field then?

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: If they are not coprime then $m = np$ for some $n$ and $x^m - 1 = (x^n - 1)^p$.

Comment: yes. thank you very much.

Comment: Suppose $ m=p-1 $, then $ \gcd(p-1, p)=1 $, but the splitting field of $ 
x^{p-1}-1 $ is $  \mathbb F_p $ itself, rather than $ \mathbb F_p(z) $ where $ z $ is a primitive root of unity of order $ p-1 $.

Answer (score 3):

The general case reduces to the one where $m$ and $p$ are coprime by noting that if they are not, then $m$ is actually a multiple of $p$, and we use the identity $x^{np} - 1 = (x^n - 1)^p$ which holds since the characteristic is $p$.

By writing $m = np^k$ for $n < p$ and iterating the above, we get that $x^m - 1$ is just a power of $x^n - 1$, so these have the same splitting field.